# CMake: Copy files from build directory to source directoy

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

My C++-Program reads and writes files. To have the input files copied **from source directory to build directory** where they are needed, I'm using this line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
configure_file(<input> <output> COPYONLY)
```

As a positive side effect QtCreator lists the files in its Project View.

Is there a way to automatically copy files **from build directory to source directy**, so that I can have the updated output files in the source directoy and also listed in QtCreator's Project View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable with it, you can probably use the same command with absolute paths:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/<path>/<input> ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/<path>/<output> COPYONLY)
```

Where [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html) is:

> [...] the full path to the top level of the current CMake build tree.

While [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html#variable:CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) is:

> [...] the full path to the top level of the current CMake source tree.

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html), `configure_file` treats in a custom way `<input>` and `<output>` only when they are relative paths, otherwise it uses them directly.
In other terms:

- `<input>` is a filename for which:

  > A relative path is treated with respect to the value of CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.

  An absolute path is just used as-is.
- `<output>` is a filename or a directory for which:

  > A relative path is treated with respect to the value of CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.

  An absolute path is just used as-is.

---

Another possible approach you can use is to rely on the [`file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command and its (let me say) `COPY` version. As from the documentation:

> The COPY signature copies files, directories, and symlinks to a destination folder. Relative input paths are evaluated with respect to the current source directory, and a relative destination is evaluated with respect to the current build directory. Copying preserves input file timestamps, and optimizes out a file if it exists at the destination with the same timestamp. Copying preserves input permissions unless explicit permissions or NO_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS are given (default is USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS).

Apparently absolute paths can be used directly as with `configure_file` and they are left untouched. Relative paths are treated differently as it happens usually with `cmake`.

Comment: Thanks. It works with absolute pathes. The only thing that is missing is that qtcreator doesn't list the file now. BTW: Using two `configure_file` statements for copying in both directions (source->build and build->source) at the same time is a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? Anyway I'm adding to the answer another possible solution you can use.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. QtCreator crashed but I guess that was for another reason. I tried it again with a second `configure_file` statement and now the file is updated and listed in qtcreator.

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer, probably `file(COPY ...)` is another way you can do that and it's more suited for your case, but it mostly depends on the actual problem.